# Highcharts solidgauge with green/yellow/red gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I would like to know if is it possible to have a gradient that starts with green on the left (0 value), fading to yellow in the middle and then fading into red at the right side of the "solidGauge" chart.

I tried some configuration in the yAxis but they don't do what i want:

```
            yAxis: {
              plotBands: [{
                  color: {
                      linearGradient:  [300, 300, 0, 0],
                      stops: [
                          [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                          [1, 'rgb(150, 200, 155)']
                      ]
                   },
                from: 0,
                to: 100
              }],
           },
```

[image]

```
            yAxis: {
                  minColor:'#55BF3B',
                  maxColor:'#DF5353',
            },
```

[image]

```
            yAxis: {
               minColor: gaugeValue >= 80 ? '#FF0000' : (gaugeValue >= 60 ? '#FFFF00' : '#00FF00'),
               maxColor: gaugeValue >= 80 ? '#FF0000' : (gaugeValue >= 60 ? '#FFFF00' : '#00FF00'),
            }
```

[image]

```
            yAxis: {
               stops: [
                    [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                    [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
               ],
            },
```

[image]

Ok I know that images have different colours because I used different Hex value, btw the result is always the same: a solid color (based on the gaugeValue).

I would like that if my value is 90% I can see gradient green to yellow to red. Something like this:

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set color for point as gradient, not for axis. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/n9gfeor2/

```
series: [{
  name: 'Speed',
  data: [{
    color: {
      linearGradient: [0, 0, 300, 0],
      stops: [
        [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
        [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
        [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
      ]
    },
    y: 80
  }]
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer:
[Highchart's gauge with gradient plotband](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538353/highcharts-gauge-with-gradient-plotband)

```
color: {
                linearGradient:  [300, 300, 0, 0],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(150, 200, 155)']
                ]
```

Comment: Unlukily it doesn't work. It seems it ignores linearGradient and radialGradient. I was looking the link suggested but the bar takes the default color